# Find max values in a nested list in Python

Tags: python, list

I want to find the index of max values in a nested list:

For example the nested list is:

[[15 16 18 19 12 11] [13 19 23 21 16 12] [12 15 17 19 20 10] [10 14 16 13  9  6]]

the max values should be 19, 23, 20, 16.

I also want to find their index in tuple format such as

19: (0,3) 23:(1,2) 20: (2,4)

I know how to find the global maximum of the nested list, but not sure how to find the max values for each list.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need a `for` loop to solve this.

I'll give you a real answer, but you will want to look into this more to understand what is going on:

```
for ii,line in enumerate(data):
    max_val = max(line)
    index   = line.index(max_val)
    print("{}:({},{})".format(max_val,ii,index),end=' ')
print()
```

a `for` loop in python is going to give you each element in an iterable.  In this case you've got a list-of-lists, so each `line` is going to be a list.  Since you want those numbered, I've put the `data` inside the `enumerate` function, which returns a pair of (,<element) which the `for` loop unpacks into the variables `ii` and `line`.
The next line `max_val` is assigned by the `max` function which returns the maximum value in the iterable `line`.
The `index` variable is set by the method `list.index` of the `line` list instance, which returns the first index of the value given to it in the list the method is called on.
Finally I print the output in the format you want by using a string and calling the `format` method to fill in the `{}` placeholders.  more information on format strings can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#custom-string-formatting).  Also, the `print` function defaults to a newline after each print; so rather than introduce string-building here, I changed the end-line to a space and added an extra print after the for-loop to get you a new-line.

There's a lot here, and I can see how you might be lost on this question.  I'm going to link to each of the built-in commands I used here so that you can learn more about python's "batteries included" functions and methods.

[for-loop flow control](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html?highlight=loop#for-statements)

[Built-in functions:](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#built-in-functions)

- [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate)
- [max](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#max)
- [print](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#print)

[Python built-in data structures](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=list#data-structures)

- [lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=list#data-structures)

Happy hacking.

Answer (score 0):

to solve your problem, i'd probably go with a dictionary comprehension (which is actually working the same way as list comprehensions)

```
{max(nested_list): (i, nested_list.index(max(nested_list))) for i, nested_list in enumerate(your_list_of_list)}
```

Using the `enumerate` python built-in function allows you to get both the index of the nested list (`i`) and its value (`nested_list`).

From there, you can easily find the maximum of each nested list with the `max` function.

Finally, the `index` method allows you to find the first occurence of the maximum value from the nested list.